# Is there any way to check if a language variable exists using preprocessors?

Tags: objective-c, c-preprocessor

I have something like this:

```
static NSString * const MyLogPrefixFormat = @"%@ - %@";
static NSString * const MyDefaultLogPrefix = @"MyApp";
#define MyLogSetPrefix(newPrefix) ; static NSString * const MyLogPrefix = newPrefix;
#define MyLogManualPrefix(messagePrefix, logMessage, args...) NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:MyLogPrefixFormat, messagePrefix, logMessage], ##args);
#define MyLog(logMessage, args...) MyLogManualPrefix(MyLogPrefix, logMessage, ##args);

- (void)myMethod
{
    MyLogSetPrefix(@"myMethod");

    MyLog(@"Message One with args 1 (%@) and 2 (%@)", arg1, arg2);
    MyLog(@"Message Two");
}
```

Which expands out to this:

```
- (void)myMethod
{
    static NSString * const MyLogPrefix = @"myMethod";

    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", MyLogPrefix, @"Message One with args 1 (%@) and 2 (%@)"], arg1, arg2);
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", MyLogPrefix, @"Message Two"]);
}
```

However, I also want it to do this:

```
- (void)myMethod
{
    MyLog(@"Message One", arg1, arg2);
    MyLog(@"Message Two");
}
```

to expand out to this:

```
- (void)myMethod
{
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", MyDefaultLogPrefix, @"Message One with args 1 (%@) and 2 (%@)"], arg1, arg2);
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", MyDefaultLogPrefix, @"Message Two"]);
}
```

To achieve this second requirement, I will need to check to see if the `MyLogPrefix` constant has been set, yet. Since it's a `static NSString * const` and not a `#define`, I can't use `#ifdef`. **How can I tell if the `MyLogPrefix` constant exists, and if not, use `MyDefaultLogPrefix`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line near the top of the .m file (outside of any methods):

```
MyLogSetPrefix(MyDefaultLogPrefix);
```

This will result in:

```
static NSString * const MyLogPrefix = @"MyApp";
```

being declared as a file global variable.

Now any method that doesn't have its own local `MyLogSetPrefix` will use this file global.

Comment: I like this! Now if I pull the log stuff out into its own file, I just do that in that file, and it'll automatically be placed into the .m files upon import! The only problem, then, is if I want a log prefix for an entire file :/

Comment: Is there any way to make the default log prefix the name of the file importing it?

Comment: Try using the `__FILE__` macro and see what that gives you.

Comment: that gives the whole path DX